# Cannot update from Python 3.7.6 to 3.9 (or anything above 3.7.6) on MacOS

Tags: python, path, upgrade, uninstallation, python-3.9

This started from when I tried to use networkx and it would not work despite pip installing it and restarting the terminal. I then realized that the version on my OS is 3.7.6

At first, I tried upgrading it via installing 3.9.5 from python.org. Then I tried correcting the file path. Then I tried following the instructions on the link below to uninstall it.

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5880/python/uninstall

Then I tried uninstalling and re-installing via homebrew, and still when I enter `$ python --version`, I get 3.7.6.

Even when I uninstall via `brew uninstall python`
, I still get that I am running version 3.7.6.

This is preventing me from running certain packages like networkx. Please guide me toward what I need to do to get either the path corrected or find out where this 3.7.6 is installed so I can uninstall it and do whatever needs to be done so that when I update python in the future, I don't need to go through all of this again to get it working properly.

Comment: Can you try out `brew uninstall python3.7`? I'm a Linux guy, not a MacOS guy, but I've seen this problem before, and sometimes it helps to specify the particular package version. `python` is just an alias, and I would guess `python3.7` is the full binary name.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, I received: `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python".`
And then when I ran `python --version`, I received
`"Python 3.7.6"`

Comment: What are the results of `whereis python`?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

When I try to install python again after uninstalling it, I get the message Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/2to3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/2to3
/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.9 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/2to3-3.9
/usr/local/bin/idle3 ->

Comment: Along with these
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/idle3
/usr/local/bin/idle3.9 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/idle3.9
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pydoc3
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.9 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pydoc3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3-config -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 ->

Comment: and these

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config